# Selenium unable to locate element event though element does exists

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

i want to get the location this store from google maps but selenium is unable to locate it. why is that?

store google maps link: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Blaze+Pizza/@24.5014283,54.387503,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5e676982d20b17:0xe2c5b69e67e4c85d!8m2!3d24.5014283!4d54.3896917

by code segment:

```
location = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text
```

Note: xPath is correct, and page is fully loading.
what do you think the problem is?

thank you

i tried different xPath and letting the page load fully, also tried scrolling a bit but still.
i want to get the text of the location.

Here's my code:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
location = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text
```

Comment: Please share ALL your Selenium code.

Answer (score 1):

First friend, it is not right to look for the xpath this way. Copying your code and correcting it would be like this ([Locating Elements - Documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

```
location = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text
```

In addition, it is necessary to wait for the element to be visible in order to extract its text ([Explicit Waits - Documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Here's the code with proposed changes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

(...)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Blaze+Pizza/@24.5014283,54.387503,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5e676982d20b17:0xe2c5b69e67e4c85d!8m2!3d24.5014283!4d54.3896917")
location = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((
                By.XPATH, '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]')))

print(location.text)
```

Comment: I have included part of my code that reaches this please. I am waiting for 5 seconds for the page to load I am also taking a screenshot and I can confirm that the element is showing. i t also gets it for some stores, and for others it doesn't.
Why can that be?

thank you for your help

Comment: I tried your way of getting the location and still it returns an error that element cant be located.

Comment: @RonyR Could you edit your question and paste the complete code? Who knows, also share the places you've been researching. That way it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

We can't see your all script so I use my own script with your link and xpath. My code gives the correct location result. Your problem may be in your code not in xpath expression.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium_stealth import stealth


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
# options.add_argument("--headless")

executable_path = "Your Chromedriver Path"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(executable_path))

driver.delete_all_cookies()

stealth(driver,
    languages=["en-EN", "en"],
    vendor="Google Inc.",
    platform="Win32",
    webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
    renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
    fix_hairline=True,
)

url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Blaze+Pizza/@24.5014283,54.387503,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5e676982d20b17:0xe2c5b69e67e4c85d!8m2!3d24.5014283!4d54.3896917"

driver.get(url)

location = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text

print(location)
```

Answer (score 0):

using the relative path made it work

```
    location = driver.find_element('xpath','//button[@data-item-id="address"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text
```